# varnish regular expression for url

Tags: javascript, regex, varnish, varnish-vcl

Need a help in creating a vcl rule to cache specific pages.
Ask is if url contain

```
/order/{x}/{y}
```

cache it (now x and y is random string which may contain alphanumeric and special char)

do not cache anything below

```
/order/{x}
/order/{x}/{y}/{z}
/order/{x}/{y}/{z}/.../{n}
```

thank you for taking look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var rgx = /order\/((?:[\x00-\xFF](?!\/))+[^/])\/((?:[\x00-\xFF](?!\/))+[^/])\s*$/gi;
rgx.test("/order/{x}/{y}");//true
rgx.test("/order/{x}");//false
rgx.test("/order/{x}/{y}/{z}");//false
rgx.test("/order/{x}/{y}/{z}/{t}");//false
```

Groups are captured as well:

```
var exec = rgx.exec("order/{x}/{y}");
exec[1];//"{x}"
exec[2];//"{y}"
```

Comment: ((?:[\x00-\xFF](?!\/))+[^/])\/((?:[\x00-\xFF](?!\/))+[^/])\s*

Perfect. Above one is working for me.